# why is there a delay when trying to update remote master on github?

Tags: git, bash, github, ssh

There was a delay in communication response time, when trying to push merged updates to remote master(GitHub).

1. It appears on top of terminal to be going from bash, to ssh. I'm talking about [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkxjN.png)  of the terminal. (huh?)
2. during the time the terminal window(top) depicts 'ssh', the entire terminal window itself is inactive, and totally blank/black. additional attempts to 'git push' is ignored. (huh?)
3. After about 30-45 seconds, the letters 'ssh' switch back to 'bash', and it appears to be back online, so to speak, and finishes performing task.
4. After said such task is complete, it outputs the correct and typical response letting me know that all is well, that the master on github now is a reflection of the master(local), indicating that I'm good to go.

YES, no harm, no foul. It worked. Technically, there is no problem. Yay.

However, huh? is still very confusing. No yay. Only boo.

I'm not even sure if this is a problem.

1. Git is communicating to Git Hub via bash ? (because this was not an issue prior to it switching to ssh).
2. Please explain why has my terminal all of a sudden, decided to communicate via ssh, and for only that one piece(point in the process).Because when I push to the remote branch, there's no hold up. It only delays when pushing to remote master.
3. Is this even a problem ? Should I just chill and wait the 30-45 sec and chalk it up to under the hood jazz that will sort itself out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Git is communicating to Git Hub via bash ?

Git does execute its commands/scripts in a bash session

> please explain why has my terminal all of a sudden, decided to communicate via ssh,

Check `git remote -v`  or `git branch -avv`: there should be an ssh url, which would make the bash `git push` switch to ssh.

> Should I just chill and wait the 30-45 sec

No, this should be very fast. Check if the issue persists when pushing additional commits on `origin/master`.
Set the set the environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND to

```
ssh -v
```

That will show you where ssh take times.